# how can i add new user in vnc viewer configuration file…?

Tags: redhat, linux, linux-networking, vnc

I have problem to connect my remote redhat linux Server from my desktop pc having Microsoft xp OS using VNC Viewer.I can access the linux machine using vnc through root user with the command 192.168.17.125:2

My requirement is to login linux machine using new user "ahis" from my desktop machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope that this link will be helpful:

http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/VNC-Server#head-2af7c99dd1f5f5b6c8bd1d4b4ada5e4823184064